# How to read table data using selenium python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, tabular

Following is the table HTML source which seems to be very complex for selenium to read its contents.. Can somebody help me, reading this data into python using selenium?

```
<div class="general_table">
    <div class="general_s">
        <div class="general_text1">Name</div>
        <div class="general_text2">Abhishek</div>
    </div>
    <div class="general_m">
        <div class="general_text1">Last Name</div>
        <div class="general_text2">Kulkarni</div>
    </div>
    <div class="general_s">
        <div class="general_text1">Phone</div>
        <div class="general_text2"> 13613123</div>
    </div>
    <div class="general_m">
        <div class="general_text1">Cell Phone</div>
        <div class="general_text2">82928091</div>
    </div>         
    <div class="general_s">
        <div class="general_text1">City</div>
        <div class="general_text2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="general_m">
        <div class="general_text1">Model</div>
        <div class="general_text2"> DELL PERC H700</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read this table using selenium webdriver, xpath seems to be the easy way -

I'm do not know python properly so the code might be wrong but the idea seems to be right  -

To find out the number of div tags with in the `general_table` we use the xpath -

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//*[@class='general_table']/div")` which will return a List with **size -  6**.

Then you can loop through each of the elements using a loop -

```
for(int i=1;i<=list.length;i++){
    String text1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='general_table']/div["+i+"]/div[1]").text;
    String text2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='general_table']/div["+i+"]/div[2]").text;
}
```

You can read all the tags in the table by this way.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as correct by ticking my answer if this solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use selenium to grab the page source (so you get the real content after all the js/ajax stuff) and something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div class="general_table">
    <div class="general_s">
        <div class="general_text1">Name</div>
        <div class="general_text2">Abhishek</div>
    </div>
    <div class="general_m">
        <div class="general_text1">Last Name</div>
        <div class="general_text2">Kulkarni</div>
    </div>
    <div class="general_s">
        <div class="general_text1">Phone</div>
        <div class="general_text2"> 13613123</div>
    </div>
    <div class="general_m">
        <div class="general_text1">Cell Phone</div>
        <div class="general_text2">82928091</div>
    </div>         
    <div class="general_s">
        <div class="general_text1">City</div>
        <div class="general_text2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="general_m">
        <div class="general_text1">Model</div>
        <div class="general_text2"> DELL PERC H700</div>
    </div>
</div>""")

def tags(iterable):
    return filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, basestring), iterable)

for table in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'general_table'}):
    for line in tags(table.contents):
        for i, column in enumerate(tags(line.contents)):
            if column.string:
                print column.string.strip(),
            if i:
                print ',',
            else:
                print ':',
        print ''
```

Result:

```
Name : Abhishek , 
Last Name : Kulkarni , 
Phone : 13613123 , 
Cell Phone : 82928091 , 
City : 
Model : DELL PERC H700 ,
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo, This solutions also works for me though getting source using selenium is not a good idea.. hence I will go for Hari's solution..