# how to get the data from the table with python selenium if the class and xpath are always changing?

Tags: python, regex, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32209xB">
                  <tbody>
                   <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top">
                     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32206" cols="8" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                      <tbody>
                       <tr height="0">
                        <td style="WIDTH:56.91mm;min-width:56.91mm">
                        </td>

                       </tr>
                       <tr valign="top">

                        <td class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32126c Pe5cd046a24fa44ef80e79727141463c6_1_r7">
                         <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32126">
                          Total Tutorials
                         </div>
                        </td>


                        <td class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32144c Pe5cd046a24fa44ef80e79727141463c6_1_r7 Pe5cd046a24fa44ef80e79727141463c6_1_r6">
                         <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32144">
                          <div style="WIDTH:19.98mm;">
                           <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32141">
                            <span class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32140">
                             Attendance
                            </span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32143">
                            <span class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32142">
                             %
                            </span>
                           </div>
                          </div>
                         </div>
                        </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr valign="top">
                        <td class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32149cl Pe5cd046a24fa44ef80e79727141463c6_1_r5" style="HEIGHT:6.35mm;">
                         <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32149">
                          CSFf
                         </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32153cr">
                         <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32153">
                          9
                         </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32157cr">
                         <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32157">
                          7
                         </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32161cl">
                         <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32161">
                          0
                         </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32165cl">
                         <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32165">
                          0
                         </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32169cr">
                         <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32169">
                          4.0000
                         </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32173cr">
                         <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32173">
                          4.0000
                         </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32177cr Pe5cd046a24fa44ef80e79727141463c6_1_r6">
                         <div class="A490847cc28c94895bcf96e98abdb2b32177">
                          84.62
                         </div>
                        </td>
```

I am working with python selenium web driver.I want the loop through the table for the text inside the `td` inside `tr` tag [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533982/how-to-read-table-data-using-selenium-python)
But problem here is the class name is always changing and xpath and css_selector is also changing.example xpath will be like this `.//*[@id='P825048fc6b084257a601fde4805c8c33_1_oReportCell']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[8]/div` 
But the `id` is changing always.so couldn't apply `driver.find_element_by_id()`.I think regular expressions or BeautifulSoup can be used to solve this.I am beginner to regex.So is there any way this could be solved?

Comment: Your html is not complete enough to determine how to do this. Could you instead post the whole table, with only some rows? So <table><tbody><tr><td><table><tbody><tr>   <<< that whole table, with only the first two rows on each table included.

Comment: Your xpath already looks way  over complicated. What page are you scraping and what do you want?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hello!that is aspx site in which there is a table and I want to get the data from the table

Comment: There has to be a much easier way, can you share the site url?

Comment: that is a webapp you can get that table only after the login!

Comment: To get a proper answer you will need to post the full html here  or a link to the html.

Comment: [visit link](https://gist.github.com/srikar0896/32e4fa6f096145b0a32489002c3cd92f) see the description of the gist.note that classes and id's keep on changing

Comment: [link updated](https://gist.github.com/srikar0896/32e4fa6f096145b0a32489002c3cd92f#file-index-html-L937)

Comment: is CS 261-Computer Network always there?

Comment: no, for different users it is different

Comment: Try using `"//*[contains(@id,'oReportCell')]"`, I presume only the starting numbers change?

Comment: It works with your html in the link, add a different sample that it does not work with, there has to be some common logic

Comment: Is that the complete solution.because that selects `td id="P825048fc6b084257a601fde4805c8c33_1_oReportCell">` which is parent table but how to get the values

Comment: your xpath gives [link](https://gist.github.com/srikar0896/32e4fa6f096145b0a32489002c3cd92f#file-index-html-L402) but I want the value which is in line 937

Comment: If not possible please provide answer supposing that CS 261-Computer Network is always there

Comment: It worked.I added to your answer `//*[contains(@id,'oReportCell')]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent of table id has kind of unique in which every time the number changes but the ReportCell is appended to it so using that we can find its children like this

```
//*[contains(@id,'oReportCell')]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use this xpath, not sure if it's 100% correct:

```
//div[text() = 'CSFf']/ancestor::tr/td[not(descendant::div[text() = 'CSFf'])]/div
```

To make it variable:

```
public String getXpathForTableThing(String searchString) {

    return "//div[text() = '"+searchString+"']/ancestor::tr/td[not(descendant::div[text() = '"+searchString+"'])]/div";
}
```

I'm not experienced with python but I'm sure you get the idea and can transform this to a python function.

Comment: I'll try this  and let you know

Comment: working.But not accurately.This selects the div's which shouldn't be included

Comment: but what if in the place  of CSFf there is another text.I have to change the text to the desired string But can there any way to get this without including the text CSFf.?

Comment: What I do when I have a badly made html table like this is create a function for my xpath where I supply the text used to find the rows.

Comment: what if I want to get them what ever is there in that

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand your question.

Comment: Here you are passing a string `CSFf` right.but I want to get the all the values with out passing the string.because for different users there are different values.

Comment: I am sorry but unless you know for the user what the CSFf value is going to be, or can find that value somewhere on a page, it is rather impossible to find a *good* xpath for your table structure. It might be possible to find a working xpath, but that would take more time than I am willing to put in.

Comment: Thanks  for the ideas thats helpfull